# Brew won't uninstall a package because it can't find another formula

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to get rid of the php56-pdo-pgsql formula installed by Brew so that I can install it again with the --without-homebrew-php option. pgsql is installed in the copy of PHP that came with OS X 10.12. However when I try to uninstall it like this

```
brew uninstall php56-pdo-pgsql
```

brew complains like this

```
Error: No available formula with the name "mashape/kong/luajit"
```

Comment: Have you tried brew `uninstall php56` all together and after `brew cleanup`?

Comment: I hadn't tried `cleanup` before but I have now and I get the same result with php56

Comment: Do you have command-line tools installed? Try typing `gcc` in terminal.

Comment: Yes I do.  Why ?

Comment: Try running `ack` or `grep` in the `/usr/local/Cellar` dir searching for `mashape/kong/luajit`. Likely something is still referencing the formula.

Answer (score 1):

First steps would be to `brew update` (twice) then `brew doctor` to make sure all is good in brew. Then check that the XCode command line tools and Xcode itself are up to date.

If, after that, you still get the problem you may have found a formula bug so file an issue at https://github.com/Homebrew/brew